# AWS Lambda Python script. How do I return an object and keep the scipt running in the background?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a AWS lambda script that is triggered by a post request. The script takes about 10 minutes to run. When the POST request/trigger is received, I want to return a guid/identifier before/at the same time as running the script. That way, a user can use that guid to check the progress of the script via a db config I have not yet made.
My problem is that when my lambda_handler gives a return object, the script stops running. I want to return the guid, and keep the script running.

Comment: lamdba functions aren't really meant to keep running, though

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with only lambda function.
If you want to achieve your goal, you must use Lambda with Step Functions to build a complete workflow:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html
```

You have to break your lambda into 2 parts. The first one return the guid/identifier. The other continue processing the logic after the first lambda returns the result.

Step Functions configuration example:

```
{
  "StartAt": "LambdaFunction1",
  // The first lambda that return the guid/identifier
  "States": {
    "LambdaFunction1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda1:here",
      "Next": "LambdaFunction2"
    },
    "LambdaFunction2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda2:here",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```